# 'many tests' fail during the php-amqp 'make test'

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqp

the result of 'make test'
[image]

I use the `php-5.6.0`  ,and `amqp-1.4.0`, `rabbitmq-c-0.5.2` .

I can finish the process,but when I run the "make test",I can't get the all passed results.

Comment: php-amqp 1.4.0 is quite outdated, try latest 1.6.0 beta or report the issue to https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/issues with all details (read [How To Report A Problem](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp#how-to-report-a-problem) first).

Comment: I have tried the 1.6.0beta2 ,and get the same results.Number of tests :  107               107
Tests skipped   :    0 (  0.0%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   76 ( 71.0%) ( 71.0%)
Expected fail   :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests passed    :   31 ( 29.0%) ( 29.0%)

Comment: Create an issue and provide all necessary info, as I suggested in comment above. Without details it is hard to tell what's wrong. Maybe you use a bit old RabbitMQ version, they changed error messages in few latest releases and we write tests and test against latest RabbitMQ version.

Comment: I have create the issue,https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/issues/160. And I don't install the RabbitMQ in the machine, so this has nothing to do with RabbitMQ version. At the same time ,I think that the 'make test' don't use the real rabbitmq ..